# Running Solaris x86. I cannot see the login window

Tags: laptop, login, blank-screen, solaris-10

I'm running Solaris 10 1/13 (x86) on a HP EliteBook 8470p laptop. I log into the CDE desktop. Everything (audio, video and network) seems to be running ok until I logout. When I logout, the screen goes blank (the same color as the workspace background), but the login window does not re-appear. So far, the only way I've been able to recover is to reboot the laptop. *Update: I learned I can "logout" if I "kill -9" my Xorg process. This returns me to the login window.*

What I've tried/learned so far:

1. The same thing happens if I log into the Java desktop.
2. All users are affected, including root.
3. I can still login remotely with rlogin and ssh.
4. I can still login using remote desktop from another Solaris x86 workstation.
5. The login window appears to be there, I just can't see it. First, I login remotely with rlogin. Next, I enter my username & password on the laptop. Then from my rlogin session, I do "ps -deaf" and I can see a list of my desktop's login processes. I just can't see anything on the screen. I can logout of the desktop (using keystrokes in the blind to find the logout). Again, I use "ps -deaf" to verify the logout worked.
6. The ps command confirms dtlogin, dtgreet, and Xorg are still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not my preferred solution, but it works and allows me to continue with my real work.

I overwrote XSession_Exit in /etc/dt/appconfig/types/C/dt.dt to run a shell script. That shell script kills the Xorg belonging to the user, which returns the user to the login window. I also cutomized /etc/dt/config/Xreset to call a script to restart cde-login if Xorg doesn't restart.

This is a crude solution, but it will do for now.